# RepoDB throwing SqlConnection Exception

Tags: .net-core, micro-orm

I am trying this out for the first time but it is not working. I have `RepoDb` nuget package installed in a Class library project but don't know where to call the `RepoDb.SqlServerBootstrap.Initialize();` method. It wasn't specified in the docs. When I run it, I get the exeception

> {"There is no database setting mapping found for
> 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'. Make sure to install the
> correct extension library and call the bootstrapper method. You can
> also visit the library's installation page
> (http://repodb.net/tutorials/installation)."}

Help resolve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please install the `RepoDb.SqlServer` Nuget package as well. Once installed, you can then call the bootstrapper's `Initialize()` method. Here is the [link](https://repodb.net/tutorial/get-started-sqlserver) to the documentation.

Comment: Thanks Michael. But I don't know where exactly to call the method. Remember that it is a Class Library I'm using.

Comment: Our usual approach is to expose a static method in your class library liked (i.e: ClassLibrary.Initializer.Bootstrap). Then inside this method, call the 'RepoDb.SqlServerInitializer()' of RepoDb. After that, have this static method of yours be called somewhere in the 'Startup' method. In the event that you do not like that, you can always call the 'RepoDb.SqlServer.Initialize()' method in a non-static method. RepoDb on the other hand has a 'check' internally whether the initialization is already completed. Hope that helps!

Comment: This statement "RepoDb on the other hand has a 'check' internally whether the initialization is already completed" just cleared my concern if I have to delete the method after the initialization. Thank you so much.

Comment: Please revert anytime if you have problem. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

When using **System.Data.SqlClient** instead of **Microsoft.Data.SqlClient**, you have to add these lines, as described in
https://repodb.net/tutorial/installation:

```
var dbSetting = new SqlServerDbSetting();
DbSettingMapper.Add<SqlConnection>(dbSetting, true);
DbHelperMapper.Add<SqlConnection>(new SqlServerDbHelper(), true);
StatementBuilderMapper.Add<SqlConnection>(new SqlServerStatementBuilder(dbSetting), true);
```